# Symfony Doctrine if statement in querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to insert IF statement inside doctrine query builder? For example: I have `User` and `Group` entities with OneToMany relationship. Group has boolean field `hidden`. How to create query builder which would select groups that are `hidden` = false if `Group` owner is not current user. So that only group owner can see hidden=true groups. and other users can only see hidden=false groups

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('group')
        ->where('group.owner = :userId')
        ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
        ->orderBy('group.created', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fit your needs

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('group');

$qb
    ->where(
      $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('group.owner', ':userId'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('group.hidden', true)
      )
    )
    ->orWhere($qb->expr()->eq('group.hidden', false))
    ->setParameter('userId', $user->getId())
    ->orderBy('group.created', 'DESC');
```

First part of query will keep a row only if current user is the owner and group is hidden.

Second part will include all non-hidden groups.